# Postgresql : How can I determine how many characters in a text

Tags: postgresql

a column has type text and its data looks like "{U}{R}" or "{3}{U}{U}{U}".
How can I determine how many "U" contains this column?
I want to select those data who has at least one and at most three {U}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the code U and compare the size before/after removing it. This difference is the number of occurrence.

```
select length('{3}{U}{U}{U}{R}{R}')-length(translate('{3}{U}{U}{U}{R}{R}','U','')) AS U_CNT;
```

--> 3

or more generaly

```
select length(colname)-length(translate(colname,'U','')) AS U_CNT;
```